# Unable to stop CoroutineWorker when condition fails

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I'm using `CoroutineWorker` for background task. Here is the code snippet

```
class SimpleWorker(context: Context) : CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams) {
     override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope{
         //obtain settings info saved as local file
         val settingsInfo = obtainSettings(context) 

         if(null == settingsInfo) {
            Result.failure()
         }

         Log.i(TAG, "Valid settings found, proceed")
         val isUploadEnabled = settingsInfo.isUploadEnabled //error when settingInfo is null
      }
}
```

In the event of null settings, I would expect the worker to send failure signals and stop running rest of the code. Instead it proceeds and breaks further down. Is `Result.failure()` not doing what it is meant to be doing or do I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to actually call `return` with the `Result.failure()` object:

```
if(null == settingsInfo) {
    return@coroutineScope Result.failure()
}
```

Otherwise you're just creating a `Result.failure()` object and not doing anything with it.